# Extract img inside description tag of xml file using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am doing parsing. I want to get the image inside the description tag. I am using urllib and BeautifulSoup. I can get the image which is inside the separate tag but I can't get the image inside the description tag in encoded format.

Xml code

```
<item>
         <title>Kidnapped NDC member and political activist tells his story</title>
         <link>http://www.yementimes.com/en/1724/news/3065</link>
         <description>&lt;img src="http://www.yementimes.com/images/thumbnails/cms-thumb-000003081.jpg" border="0" align="left" hspace="5" /&gt;
‘I kept telling them that they would never break me and that the change we demanded in 2011 would come whether they wanted it or not’
&lt;br clear="all"&gt;</description>
```

views.py

```
for q in b.findAll('item'):
            d={}
            d['desc']=strip_tags(q.description.string).strip('&nbsp')
            if q.guid:
                d['link']=q.guid.string
            else:   
                d['link']=strip_tags(q.comments)
            d['title']=q.title.string
            for r in q.findAll('enclosure'):
                d['image']=r['url']
            arr.append(d)
```

Can anyone please give me an idea to do it..
This is what I have done it to parse image inside the separate tag...
I tried to get if it is inside description but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract all content from `<description>`, create a new `BeautifulSoup` object with it and search for `src` attribute of first `<img>` element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 
import html.parser

h = html.parser.HTMLParser()

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')
for i in soup.find_all('item'):
    d = BeautifulSoup(h.unescape(i.description.string))
    print(d.img['src'])
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
http://www.yementimes.com/images/thumbnails/cms-thumb-000003081.jpg
```